# How to create bottom actionsheet with animation view like Facebook IOS

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, swift4.2

I want to create a modal view like Facebook similar like below:

[image]

So on the tap of three dots ie more icon , i want to create a modal which will appear on the click of a button and then it shouldbe exited while dragging it down.

I tried the example from the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acPVLXQshYk)

But I am not getting the similar behaviour. Please let me know what should I use as I am not using storyboard also.

Thanks!